# how to eliminate a unique record using SQL?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table with 3 columns. `cid` is the user, `when` is a timestamp of some transaction, and the 3rd column is me fumbling with how to achieve my objective.

In DB2, using this query:

`SELECT cid, when, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cid ORDER BY when ASC) AS cid_when_rank 
FROM (SELECT  DISTINCT cid, when FROM yrb_purchase ORDER BY cid) AS temp`

I get this table:

`CID    WHEN                                    CID_WHEN_RANK
     1 1999-04-20-12.12.00.000000                    1
     1 2001-12-01-11.59.00.000000                    2
     2 1998-08-08-17.33.00.000000                    1
     2 1999-02-13-15.13.00.000000                    2
     2 1999-04-16-11.46.00.000000                    3
     2 2001-02-23-12.37.00.000000                    4
     2 2001-04-24-17.02.00.000000                    5
     2 2001-10-21-11.05.00.000000                    6
     2 2001-12-01-15.39.00.000000                    7
     3 1998-01-27-09.19.00.000000                    1
     3 2001-10-06-11.12.00.000000                    2
     4 2000-06-13-09.45.00.000000                    1
     4 2001-06-30-13.58.00.000000                    2
     4 2001-08-11-17.40.00.000000                    3
     5 2001-07-17-16.27.00.000000                    1
     6 2000-05-18-11.43.00.000000                    1
     6 2001-07-08-18.09.00.000000                    2
     6 2001-10-02-12.37.00.000000                    3
     7 1999-06-15-12.13.00.000000                    1
     7 2000-05-05-14.49.00.000000                    2
     7 2000-09-26-16.32.00.000000                    3
     8 1999-01-19-09.32.00.000000                    1
     8 1999-08-02-09.20.00.000000                    2
     8 2000-07-03-12.39.00.000000                    3
     8 2001-08-13-13.11.00.000000                    4
     8 2001-10-18-10.18.00.000000                    5
     9 2001-09-10-13.03.00.000000                    1
    10 2000-03-11-10.05.00.000000                    1
    10 2001-03-11-15.46.00.000000                    2
    10 2001-04-29-18.30.00.000000                    3
    11 2001-07-27-11.45.00.000000                    1
    12 1999-02-07-10.59.00.000000                    1
    12 2001-08-24-11.12.00.000000                    2
    13 1998-03-17-14.04.00.000000                    1
    13 2001-05-18-10.11.00.000000                    2
    13 2001-09-14-12.56.00.000000                    3
    14 2001-10-10-17.18.00.000000                    1
    15 2000-12-01-18.27.00.000000                    1
    16 2000-01-04-14.18.00.000000                    1
    16 2001-02-27-15.08.00.000000                    2
    16 2001-11-16-09.52.00.000000                    3
    17 1998-04-08-17.59.00.000000                    1
    17 1999-06-07-10.13.00.000000                    2
    17 2001-09-13-12.08.00.000000                    3
    18 2001-09-22-10.01.00.000000                    1
    19 1999-03-09-12.11.00.000000                    1
    19 2001-07-23-09.27.00.000000                    2
    19 2001-12-01-16.10.00.000000                    3
    20 1999-11-22-14.29.00.000000                    1
    20 2000-05-27-17.56.00.000000                    2
    20 2001-06-01-09.37.00.000000                    3
    21 1998-02-17-16.08.00.000000                    1
    21 2000-02-15-13.22.00.000000                    2
    21 2001-03-10-15.05.00.000000                    3
    21 2001-03-10-16.22.00.000000                    4
    21 2001-10-25-10.15.00.000000                    5
    21 2001-11-19-11.02.00.000000                    6
    22 2001-03-04-17.13.00.000000                    1
    22 2001-08-16-16.59.00.000000                    2
    22 2001-10-23-11.24.00.000000                    3
    23 1998-07-04-16.33.00.000000                    1
    23 2000-09-26-13.17.00.000000                    2
    23 2000-09-27-12.27.00.000000                    3
    23 2001-06-23-16.45.00.000000                    4
    23 2001-10-27-18.01.00.000000                    5
    24 2001-10-23-14.59.00.000000                    1
    25 2001-03-14-09.26.00.000000                    1
    25 2001-11-30-14.23.00.000000                    2
    26 2001-04-27-15.07.00.000000                    1
    26 2001-06-30-11.26.00.000000                    2
    26 2001-12-01-18.04.00.000000                    3
    27 2000-06-05-09.44.00.000000                    1
    28 1999-07-17-10.14.00.000000                    1
    28 2001-02-03-15.50.00.000000                    2
    28 2001-02-13-12.08.00.000000                    3
    28 2001-07-20-16.52.00.000000                    4
    29 2001-06-10-17.16.00.000000                    1
    29 2001-09-20-10.19.00.000000                    2
    30 1999-05-22-16.59.00.000000                    1
    30 2001-10-20-15.28.00.000000                    2
    30 2001-12-01-14.50.00.000000                    3
    32 1999-05-05-14.20.00.000000                    1
    32 2000-05-12-13.51.00.000000                    2
    32 2001-05-18-10.43.00.000000                    3
    33 1999-02-07-18.58.00.000000                    1
    33 1999-09-30-14.05.00.000000                    2
    33 2001-09-18-12.48.00.000000                    3
    34 1999-05-29-15.57.00.000000                    1
    35 2001-03-19-18.38.00.000000                    1
    35 2001-03-28-15.49.00.000000                    2
    36 1999-06-22-11.42.00.000000                    1
    36 1999-10-30-15.25.00.000000                    2
    36 2000-01-27-10.17.00.000000                    3
    36 2000-11-04-09.06.00.000000                    4
    37 1999-01-11-09.51.00.000000                    1
    37 2000-11-25-17.53.00.000000                    2
    37 2000-12-01-17.21.00.000000                    3
    37 2001-10-21-16.49.00.000000                    4
    38 1997-10-11-17.15.00.000000                    1
    39 2000-03-09-13.46.00.000000                    1
    39 2001-01-09-16.22.00.000000                    2
    39 2001-07-03-14.12.00.000000                    3
    40 1998-07-27-17.39.00.000000                    1
    40 1999-01-27-09.36.00.000000                    2
    40 1999-06-12-17.18.00.000000                    3
    40 2000-05-17-14.17.00.000000                    4
    40 2001-04-08-15.39.00.000000                    5
    40 2001-09-30-10.26.00.000000                    6
    41 1998-06-05-10.06.00.000000                    1
    41 1998-08-23-09.39.00.000000                    2
    41 1999-12-01-18.42.00.000000                    3
    41 2001-03-30-15.26.00.000000                    4
    41 2001-11-15-15.33.00.000000                    5
    42 2000-06-22-12.16.00.000000                    1
    42 2001-01-13-15.03.00.000000                    2
    42 2001-08-19-14.18.00.000000                    3
    43 1998-07-07-11.29.00.000000                    1
    43 1999-01-22-15.46.00.000000                    2
    43 2000-08-04-12.16.00.000000                    3
    43 2001-03-17-14.18.00.000000                    4
    44 1999-11-03-09.32.00.000000                    1
    44 2001-05-26-17.23.00.000000                    2
    44 2001-07-18-12.59.00.000000                    3
    44 2001-10-23-10.04.00.000000                    4
    44 2001-11-09-16.18.00.000000                    5
    45 2000-03-19-10.31.00.000000                    1
    45 2001-07-14-11.36.00.000000                    2`

I am trying to eliminate all the customers `(cid)` who have made only one purchase. For example, `cid=5 and cid=9` are good examples. The logic is that if they have a `cid_when_rank=1`, but no `cid_when_rank=2`, I need to drop those tuples. I have been breaking my head using **INTERSECTION, EXCEPT**, and using logic in the `WHERE claus`e, but no luck. I looked online on how to eliminate `DISTINCT` records, but  all I found was people discovering the `DISTINCT` keyword.

Please do not suggest hard coding `cid=5 or cid=9` as there are more than those two records in the table.

Can you please suggest a simple SQL way to get this done. Please be aware I am not very strong at SQL yet, and would appreciate the most basic answer

Thanks in advance!

************************************EDIT #1**********************************

when I tried the first and second suggested answers my table went from 127 records to 287. I am trying to simply remove the records where a cid has a rank of 1, and does not have a rank of 2. Hope you can help.
The results of both suggested answers yield the same table:
`CID    WHEN                                CID_WHEN_RANK
     1 1999-04-20-12.12.00.000000                    1
     1 2001-12-01-11.59.00.000000                    2
     1 2001-12-01-11.59.00.000000                    3
     1 2001-12-01-11.59.00.000000                    4
     1 2001-12-01-11.59.00.000000                    5
     2 1998-08-08-17.33.00.000000                    1
     2 1998-08-08-17.33.00.000000                    2
     2 1999-02-13-15.13.00.000000                    3
     2 1999-04-16-11.46.00.000000                    4
     2 2001-02-23-12.37.00.000000                    5
     2 2001-04-24-17.02.00.000000                    6
     2 2001-04-24-17.02.00.000000                    7
     2 2001-04-24-17.02.00.000000                    8
     2 2001-10-21-11.05.00.000000                    9
     2 2001-10-21-11.05.00.000000                   10
     2 2001-12-01-15.39.00.000000                   11
     3 1998-01-27-09.19.00.000000                    1
     3 1998-01-27-09.19.00.000000                    2
     3 1998-01-27-09.19.00.000000                    3
     3 2001-10-06-11.12.00.000000                    4
     3 2001-10-06-11.12.00.000000                    5
     3 2001-10-06-11.12.00.000000                    6
     3 2001-10-06-11.12.00.000000                    7
     3 2001-10-06-11.12.00.000000                    8
     4 2000-06-13-09.45.00.000000                    1
     4 2001-06-30-13.58.00.000000                    2
     4 2001-06-30-13.58.00.000000                    3
     4 2001-06-30-13.58.00.000000                    4
     4 2001-08-11-17.40.00.000000                    5
     5 2001-07-17-16.27.00.000000                    1
     5 2001-07-17-16.27.00.000000                    2
     5 2001-07-17-16.27.00.000000                    3
     5 2001-07-17-16.27.00.000000                    4
     5 2001-07-17-16.27.00.000000                    5
     5 2001-07-17-16.27.00.000000                    6
     5 2001-07-17-16.27.00.000000                    7
     6 2000-05-18-11.43.00.000000                    1
     6 2000-05-18-11.43.00.000000                    2
     6 2000-05-18-11.43.00.000000                    3
     6 2001-07-08-18.09.00.000000                    4
     6 2001-07-08-18.09.00.000000                    5
     6 2001-10-02-12.37.00.000000                    6
     7 1999-06-15-12.13.00.000000                    1
     7 1999-06-15-12.13.00.000000                    2
     7 2000-05-05-14.49.00.000000                    3
     7 2000-09-26-16.32.00.000000                    4
     8 1999-01-19-09.32.00.000000                    1
     8 1999-08-02-09.20.00.000000                    2
     8 2000-07-03-12.39.00.000000                    3
     8 2000-07-03-12.39.00.000000                    4
     8 2001-08-13-13.11.00.000000                    5
     8 2001-10-18-10.18.00.000000                    6
     8 2001-10-18-10.18.00.000000                    7
     9 2001-09-10-13.03.00.000000                    1
     9 2001-09-10-13.03.00.000000                    2
     9 2001-09-10-13.03.00.000000                    3
     9 2001-09-10-13.03.00.000000                    4
     9 2001-09-10-13.03.00.000000                    5
     9 2001-09-10-13.03.00.000000                    6
     9 2001-09-10-13.03.00.000000                    7
     9 2001-09-10-13.03.00.000000                    8
    10 2000-03-11-10.05.00.000000                    1
    10 2001-03-11-15.46.00.000000                    2
    10 2001-03-11-15.46.00.000000                    3
    10 2001-04-29-18.30.00.000000                    4
    10 2001-04-29-18.30.00.000000                    5
    11 2001-07-27-11.45.00.000000                    1
    11 2001-07-27-11.45.00.000000                    2
    11 2001-07-27-11.45.00.000000                    3
    11 2001-07-27-11.45.00.000000                    4
    11 2001-07-27-11.45.00.000000                    5
    12 1999-02-07-10.59.00.000000                    1
    12 2001-08-24-11.12.00.000000                    2
    12 2001-08-24-11.12.00.000000                    3
    12 2001-08-24-11.12.00.000000                    4
    13 1998-03-17-14.04.00.000000                    1
    13 2001-05-18-10.11.00.000000                    2
    13 2001-05-18-10.11.00.000000                    3
    13 2001-05-18-10.11.00.000000                    4
    13 2001-09-14-12.56.00.000000                    5
    14 2001-10-10-17.18.00.000000                    1
    14 2001-10-10-17.18.00.000000                    2
    14 2001-10-10-17.18.00.000000                    3
    14 2001-10-10-17.18.00.000000                    4
    14 2001-10-10-17.18.00.000000                    5
    14 2001-10-10-17.18.00.000000                    6
    14 2001-10-10-17.18.00.000000                    7
    14 2001-10-10-17.18.00.000000                    8
    15 2000-12-01-18.27.00.000000                    1
    15 2000-12-01-18.27.00.000000                    2
    15 2000-12-01-18.27.00.000000                    3
    15 2000-12-01-18.27.00.000000                    4
    15 2000-12-01-18.27.00.000000                    5
    16 2000-01-04-14.18.00.000000                    1
    16 2001-02-27-15.08.00.000000                    2
    16 2001-02-27-15.08.00.000000                    3
    16 2001-02-27-15.08.00.000000                    4
    16 2001-11-16-09.52.00.000000                    5
    16 2001-11-16-09.52.00.000000                    6
    16 2001-11-16-09.52.00.000000                    7
    17 1998-04-08-17.59.00.000000                    1
    17 1999-06-07-10.13.00.000000                    2
    17 2001-09-13-12.08.00.000000                    3
    17 2001-09-13-12.08.00.000000                    4
    17 2001-09-13-12.08.00.000000                    5
    18 2001-09-22-10.01.00.000000                    1
    18 2001-09-22-10.01.00.000000                    2
    18 2001-09-22-10.01.00.000000                    3
    19 1999-03-09-12.11.00.000000                    1
    19 1999-03-09-12.11.00.000000                    2
    19 1999-03-09-12.11.00.000000                    3
    19 2001-07-23-09.27.00.000000                    4
    19 2001-07-23-09.27.00.000000                    5
    19 2001-07-23-09.27.00.000000                    6
    19 2001-12-01-16.10.00.000000                    7
    19 2001-12-01-16.10.00.000000                    8
    19 2001-12-01-16.10.00.000000                    9
    19 2001-12-01-16.10.00.000000                   10
    19 2001-12-01-16.10.00.000000                   11
    20 1999-11-22-14.29.00.000000                    1
    20 1999-11-22-14.29.00.000000                    2
    20 2000-05-27-17.56.00.000000                    3
    20 2001-06-01-09.37.00.000000                    4
    20 2001-06-01-09.37.00.000000                    5
    21 1998-02-17-16.08.00.000000                    1
    21 2000-02-15-13.22.00.000000                    2
    21 2001-03-10-15.05.00.000000                    3
    21 2001-03-10-15.05.00.000000                    4
    21 2001-03-10-15.05.00.000000                    5
    21 2001-03-10-16.22.00.000000                    6
    21 2001-10-25-10.15.00.000000                    7
    21 2001-11-19-11.02.00.000000                    8
    21 2001-11-19-11.02.00.000000                    9
    21 2001-11-19-11.02.00.000000                   10
    21 2001-11-19-11.02.00.000000                   11
    22 2001-03-04-17.13.00.000000                    1
    22 2001-03-04-17.13.00.000000                    2
    22 2001-03-04-17.13.00.000000                    3
    22 2001-03-04-17.13.00.000000                    4
    22 2001-08-16-16.59.00.000000                    5
    22 2001-10-23-11.24.00.000000                    6
    23 1998-07-04-16.33.00.000000                    1
    23 2000-09-26-13.17.00.000000                    2
    23 2000-09-26-13.17.00.000000                    3
    23 2000-09-27-12.27.00.000000                    4
    23 2000-09-27-12.27.00.000000                    5
    23 2001-06-23-16.45.00.000000                    6
    23 2001-06-23-16.45.00.000000                    7
    23 2001-10-27-18.01.00.000000                    8
    23 2001-10-27-18.01.00.000000                    9
    23 2001-10-27-18.01.00.000000                   10
    23 2001-10-27-18.01.00.000000                   11
    24 2001-10-23-14.59.00.000000                    1
    24 2001-10-23-14.59.00.000000                    2
    24 2001-10-23-14.59.00.000000                    3
    25 2001-03-14-09.26.00.000000                    1
    25 2001-03-14-09.26.00.000000                    2
    25 2001-03-14-09.26.00.000000                    3
    25 2001-11-30-14.23.00.000000                    4
    26 2001-04-27-15.07.00.000000                    1
    26 2001-04-27-15.07.00.000000                    2
    26 2001-04-27-15.07.00.000000                    3
    26 2001-04-27-15.07.00.000000                    4
    26 2001-04-27-15.07.00.000000                    5
    26 2001-06-30-11.26.00.000000                    6
    26 2001-06-30-11.26.00.000000                    7
    26 2001-06-30-11.26.00.000000                    8
    26 2001-12-01-18.04.00.000000                    9
    26 2001-12-01-18.04.00.000000                   10
    26 2001-12-01-18.04.00.000000                   11
    27 2000-06-05-09.44.00.000000                    1
    27 2000-06-05-09.44.00.000000                    2
    28 1999-07-17-10.14.00.000000                    1
    28 2001-02-03-15.50.00.000000                    2
    28 2001-02-03-15.50.00.000000                    3
    28 2001-02-03-15.50.00.000000                    4
    28 2001-02-13-12.08.00.000000                    5
    28 2001-02-13-12.08.00.000000                    6
    28 2001-07-20-16.52.00.000000                    7
    28 2001-07-20-16.52.00.000000                    8
    29 2001-06-10-17.16.00.000000                    1
    29 2001-06-10-17.16.00.000000                    2
    29 2001-06-10-17.16.00.000000                    3
    29 2001-09-20-10.19.00.000000                    4
    29 2001-09-20-10.19.00.000000                    5
    29 2001-09-20-10.19.00.000000                    6
    30 1999-05-22-16.59.00.000000                    1
    30 2001-10-20-15.28.00.000000                    2
    30 2001-10-20-15.28.00.000000                    3
    30 2001-10-20-15.28.00.000000                    4
    30 2001-10-20-15.28.00.000000                    5
    30 2001-12-01-14.50.00.000000                    6
    30 2001-12-01-14.50.00.000000                    7
    32 1999-05-05-14.20.00.000000                    1
    32 1999-05-05-14.20.00.000000                    2
    32 2000-05-12-13.51.00.000000                    3
    32 2001-05-18-10.43.00.000000                    4
    32 2001-05-18-10.43.00.000000                    5
    32 2001-05-18-10.43.00.000000                    6
    32 2001-05-18-10.43.00.000000                    7
    32 2001-05-18-10.43.00.000000                    8
    33 1999-02-07-18.58.00.000000                    1
    33 1999-02-07-18.58.00.000000                    2
    33 1999-02-07-18.58.00.000000                    3
    33 1999-09-30-14.05.00.000000                    4
    33 1999-09-30-14.05.00.000000                    5
    33 1999-09-30-14.05.00.000000                    6
    33 2001-09-18-12.48.00.000000                    7
    33 2001-09-18-12.48.00.000000                    8
    34 1999-05-29-15.57.00.000000                    1
    34 1999-05-29-15.57.00.000000                    2
    35 2001-03-19-18.38.00.000000                    1
    35 2001-03-19-18.38.00.000000                    2
    35 2001-03-28-15.49.00.000000                    3
    35 2001-03-28-15.49.00.000000                    4
    36 1999-06-22-11.42.00.000000                    1
    36 1999-10-30-15.25.00.000000                    2
    36 1999-10-30-15.25.00.000000                    3
    36 1999-10-30-15.25.00.000000                    4
    36 2000-01-27-10.17.00.000000                    5
    36 2000-11-04-09.06.00.000000                    6
    37 1999-01-11-09.51.00.000000                    1
    37 1999-01-11-09.51.00.000000                    2
    37 1999-01-11-09.51.00.000000                    3
    37 2000-11-25-17.53.00.000000                    4
    37 2000-11-25-17.53.00.000000                    5
    37 2000-12-01-17.21.00.000000                    6
    37 2000-12-01-17.21.00.000000                    7
    37 2001-10-21-16.49.00.000000                    8
    38 1997-10-11-17.15.00.000000                    1
    38 1997-10-11-17.15.00.000000                    2
    38 1997-10-11-17.15.00.000000                    3
    38 1997-10-11-17.15.00.000000                    4
    38 1997-10-11-17.15.00.000000                    5
    38 1997-10-11-17.15.00.000000                    6
    39 2000-03-09-13.46.00.000000                    1
    39 2000-03-09-13.46.00.000000                    2
    39 2001-01-09-16.22.00.000000                    3
    39 2001-01-09-16.22.00.000000                    4
    39 2001-01-09-16.22.00.000000                    5
    39 2001-01-09-16.22.00.000000                    6
    39 2001-07-03-14.12.00.000000                    7
    40 1998-07-27-17.39.00.000000                    1
    40 1999-01-27-09.36.00.000000                    2
    40 1999-06-12-17.18.00.000000                    3
    40 1999-06-12-17.18.00.000000                    4
    40 2000-05-17-14.17.00.000000                    5
    40 2001-04-08-15.39.00.000000                    6
    40 2001-09-30-10.26.00.000000                    7
    40 2001-09-30-10.26.00.000000                    8
    41 1998-06-05-10.06.00.000000                    1
    41 1998-06-05-10.06.00.000000                    2
    41 1998-06-05-10.06.00.000000                    3
    41 1998-08-23-09.39.00.000000                    4
    41 1998-08-23-09.39.00.000000                    5
    41 1999-12-01-18.42.00.000000                    6
    41 1999-12-01-18.42.00.000000                    7
    41 1999-12-01-18.42.00.000000                    8
    41 2001-03-30-15.26.00.000000                    9
    41 2001-03-30-15.26.00.000000                   10
    41 2001-11-15-15.33.00.000000                   11
    42 2000-06-22-12.16.00.000000                    1
    42 2000-06-22-12.16.00.000000                    2
    42 2001-01-13-15.03.00.000000                    3
    42 2001-01-13-15.03.00.000000                    4
    42 2001-08-19-14.18.00.000000                    5
    42 2001-08-19-14.18.00.000000                    6
    42 2001-08-19-14.18.00.000000                    7
    42 2001-08-19-14.18.00.000000                    8
    43 1998-07-07-11.29.00.000000                    1
    43 1999-01-22-15.46.00.000000                    2
    43 2000-08-04-12.16.00.000000                    3
    43 2001-03-17-14.18.00.000000                    4
    43 2001-03-17-14.18.00.000000                    5
    43 2001-03-17-14.18.00.000000                    6
    44 1999-11-03-09.32.00.000000                    1
    44 2001-05-26-17.23.00.000000                    2
    44 2001-07-18-12.59.00.000000                    3
    44 2001-10-23-10.04.00.000000                    4
    44 2001-10-23-10.04.00.000000                    5
    44 2001-10-23-10.04.00.000000                    6
    44 2001-10-23-10.04.00.000000                    7
    44 2001-11-09-16.18.00.000000                    8
    45 2000-03-19-10.31.00.000000                    1
    45 2000-03-19-10.31.00.000000                    2
    45 2000-03-19-10.31.00.000000                    3
    45 2001-07-14-11.36.00.000000                    4`

287 record(s) selected.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `count` window function to fetch cid's when they have more than 1 row.

```
select cid,when,cid_when_rank
from (
SELECT cid, when, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cid ORDER BY when ASC) AS cid_when_rank
,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY cid) as cnt 
FROM yrb_purchase
) t
where cnt > 1
```

Edit: Based on OP's comment,

```
select cid,when,cid_when_rank
from (
SELECT cid, when, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cid ORDER BY when ASC) AS cid_when_rank
,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY cid) as cnt 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT cid, when FROM yrb_purchase) tmp
) t
where cnt > 1
```

Comment: why not use having count(*) > 1?

Comment: @vkp that eliminates every record smaller than 1 for every cid. It does eliminate the undesirable tuples, but it also takes desirable tuples with it as well.

Comment: @Mike .. it doesn't..count() over() returns the row count for each cid and will be the same on all the rows for a cid.

Comment: @vkp Sorry, I didn't fully appreciate the query - my mistake. However, when I tried your query, my table balloons from 127 records to 287. Could you please advise or suggestion on how to modify the query? thanks in advance. I put the results in the body of the question.

Comment: your initial query selects distinct times and cids from the table..so your record count is less than what it should be. this query however considers the full table for selection.

Comment: see the edit which eliminates the duplicates like in question.

Comment: @vkp Thank you very much for providing the original answer, and an even bigger thank you for the second answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using `count(*)` as a window function is a very good solution.  One way that might return results faster is `exists`:

```
select p.*
from yrb_purchase p
where exists (select 1 from yrb_purchase p2 where p2.when <> p.when);
```

Of course, if you need the row number as well, then the overhead for the count is probably immeasurable.